# How can I allow the "owners" of an Org Object in a Firebase RTB schema .read access to all "Users" that are part of the group?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, rules

Given the following firebase real-time database schema:

```
{
  "Organizations": {
    "A": {
      "name": "org a",
      "users": {
        "1": true,
        "2": true,
        "3": true
      },
      "owners": {
        "1": true,
      }
    },
    "B": {
      "name": "org B",
      "users": {
        "2": true,
        "3": true
      },
      "owners": {
        "2": true,
      }
    },
    "C": {
      "name": "org C",
      "users": {
        "1": true,
        "3": true
      },
      "owners": {
        "3": true
      }
    }
  },
  "Users": {
    "1": {
      "name": "sean",
      "organizations": {
        "A": true,
        "C": true
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "sean",
      "organizations": {
        "A": true,
        "B": true,
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "name": "sean",
      "avatar": "some image url",
      "email": "example@com.com"
      "organizations": {
        "A": true,
        "B": true,
        "C": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using real-time database rules, how can one allow all owners of an Organization to see all the user data for all the users in the organization's users object.

In other words, the goal is: list all data (name, email, avatar....) of each user of an org to an owner via the RTB connection.

I can't seem to discern how to format the child,data,children etc .write or .read rules to construct a rule set to accomplish this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To allow reading of `/Organizations/$orgId/users` by owners of that org, you'd have a rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Organizations": {
      "$orgId": {
        "users": {
          ".read": "data.parent().child('owners').child(auth.uid).exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Frank. However, if I am not mistaken, your solution only allows the *IDs* of the users in the Organization object to be read by the auth'ed user. I would need to see all the users data as well (email, name etc) which is held in a different "Users" root object.

Comment: Ah, that can't be done with your current structure. As soon as you have a "in any" condition in security rules, you're out of look. To keep the rules performing well, such searches are not possible. The normal approach is to denormalize that data: so create (on write) a list of all the users each user can see, based on their org membership.